# Android NDK Cmake linker *.so No such file or directory

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I have a very simple project, but there was a mistake in compiling that I couldn't understand.`linker command failed with exit code 1`

## System environment

```
 Windows 10 x64    
 Java 8    
 Gradle 4.5
 ------------------------------------    
 Build time:   2018-01-24 17:04:52 UTC
 Revision:     77d0ec90636f43669dc794ca17ef80dd65457bec
 Groovy:       2.4.12
 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
 JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
 OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
 NDK:          F:\Windows\android-sdk\ndk-bundle
```

## Configuration information

### build.gralde(root)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```

### build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags '-std=gnu++11', '-fpermissive', '-v'
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
}
```

### CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
find_library(log-lib log )
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib} )
```

### native-lib.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_github_gam2046_ndktest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

## Error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildJiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimationDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process F:\Windows\android-sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build E:\projects\UnitedPlatform\BasePlatform\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimationDebug\armeabi-v7a --target native-lib}
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
  Android (4691093 based on r316199) clang version 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55536e7d904e0abae47888fc7f) (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm 34361f192e41ed6e4e8f9aca80a4ea7e9856f327) (based on LLVM 6.0.2svn)
  Target: armv7-none-linux-android
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: F:\Windows\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
  Found candidate GCC installation: F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi\4.9.x
  Selected GCC installation: F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x
  Candidate multilib: thumb;@mthumb
  Candidate multilib: armv7-a;@march=armv7-a
  Candidate multilib: armv7-a/thumb;@march=armv7-a@mthumb
  Candidate multilib: .;
  Selected multilib: armv7-a/thumb;@march=armv7-a@mthumb
   "F:\\Windows\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple thumbv7-none-linux-android -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mnoexecstack -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name native-lib.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-feature -fp-only-sp -target-feature +d16 -target-feature +vfp3 -target-feature -fp16 -target-feature -vfp4 -target-feature -fp-armv8 -target-feature -neon -target-feature -crypto -target-abi aapcs-linux -mfloat-abi soft -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -ffunction-sections -coverage-notes-file "E:\\projects\\UnitedPlatform\\BasePlatform\\app\\.externalNativeBuild\\cmake\\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimationDebug\\armeabi-v7a\\CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.gcno" -resource-dir "F:\\Windows\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\lib64\\clang\\6.0.2" -dependency-file "CMakeFiles\\native-lib.dir\\src\\main\\cpp\\native-lib.cpp.o.d" -sys-header-deps -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/support/include -isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D native_lib_EXPORTS -D __ANDROID_API__=19 -D ANDROID -isysroot F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -internal-isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/local/include -internal-isystem "F:\\Windows\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\lib64\\clang\\6.0.2\\include" -internal-externc-isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/include -internal-externc-isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include -O0 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=gnu++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "E:\\projects\\UnitedPlatform\\BasePlatform\\app\\.externalNativeBuild\\cmake\\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimationDebug\\armeabi-v7a" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -femulated-tls -stack-protector 2 -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -x c++ "E:\\projects\\UnitedPlatform\\BasePlatform\\app\\src\\main\\cpp\\native-lib.cpp"
  clang -cc1 version 6.0.2 based upon LLVM 6.0.2svn default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
  ignoring nonexistent directory "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/local/include"
  ignoring nonexistent directory "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/include"
  #include "..." search starts here:
  #include <...> search starts here:
   F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include
   F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/support/include
   F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include
   F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
   F:\Windows\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\6.0.2\include
   F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include
  End of search list.
  [2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimation\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so
  FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && F:\Windows\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -v -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimation\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog -latomic -lm "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_static.a" "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++abi.a" "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libandroid_support.a" "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libunwind.a" "-ldl" && cd ."
  Android (4691093 based on r316199) clang version 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55536e7d904e0abae47888fc7f) (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm 34361f192e41ed6e4e8f9aca80a4ea7e9856f327) (based on LLVM 6.0.2svn)
  Target: armv7-none-linux-android
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: F:\Windows\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
  Found candidate GCC installation: F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi\4.9.x
  Selected GCC installation: F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x
  Candidate multilib: thumb;@mthumb
  Candidate multilib: armv7-a;@march=armv7-a
  Candidate multilib: armv7-a/thumb;@march=armv7-a@mthumb
  Candidate multilib: .;
  Selected multilib: armv7-a/thumb;@march=armv7-a@mthumb
   "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\\ld" --sysroot=F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -X --eh-frame-hdr -m armelf_linux_eabi -shared -o "..\\..\\..\\..\\build\\intermediates\\cmake\\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimation\\debug\\obj\\armeabi-v7a\\libnative-lib.so" "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib\\crtbegin_so.o" -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a "-LF:\\Windows\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\lib64\\clang\\6.0.2\\lib\\linux\\arm" -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/armv7-a/thumb -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/../lib/armv7-a/thumb -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/../../lib -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb -LF:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib --exclude-libs libgcc.a --exclude-libs libatomic.a --build-id --warn-shared-textrel --fatal-warnings --fix-cortex-a8 --exclude-libs libunwind.a --no-undefined -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -soname libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -llog -latomic -lm F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_static.a F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++abi.a F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libandroid_support.a F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libunwind.a -ldl -lm -lgcc -ldl -lc -lgcc -ldl "F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib\\crtend_so.o"
  F:/Windows/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: fatal error: ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\JiangsuTelecomNormalIntegratedBrowserWithAnimation\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so: open: No such file or directory
  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

### Some amazing things

The same code, system and environment, `git clone` to another local location, can be compiled normally. But `git diff` shows no difference.

More miraculously, if I **copy** the code to another local location ( e.g. from disk D to disk E), it will compile normally. I checked that the disk has a lot of free space. If you rename the directory in its original location, the compilation will still fail.

Similarly, I have tried to kill all `java.exe` processes. Restart the computer, etc. The situation remains the same.

I can't understand why the same code will cause compilation failure in different disk locations. According to the information provided by the compiler, it is linked to the target file, but there is no more valid information.
I also tried compiling this code in Linux without any problems

Comment: install NDK manually and give the path where you have saved

Comment: @bugfreerammohan I have specified the path to NDK in the file(local.properties : `ndk.dir`). And I tried to remove CMAKE and NDK and then install them through SDK Manager again. The situation remains the same.

Comment: If you execute the failing linker command (the thing after the `FAILED: ` print) manually, does it produce errors?

Comment: It would not surprise me if you are running into windows path length limits, but the linker command should point that out.